# Create multiple "administrative" geographies in Tableau and filter

Tags: tableau

We have shapefiles for:

```
a) voting districts
b) Wards
c) Neighborhoods
D) Police Districts
```

which all overlap in non-uniform ways. We also have other data around population, income, etc that we would like to visualize.

How do we create one map in which each shapefiles above is a single layer (in Tableau, ideally). It sounds like this should be obvious, but I can not find the solution I'm looking for.

For example: One layer would be voting district, a 2nd would be ward, and a third would be neighborhood. We could then look at income in the same viz across all three and see if/how income changes as those administrative groupings change.

Tableau version: 10.5.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this was impossible for a long-time, and then made possible using the 'dual axis' hack, but adding 3+ layers only became possible in 2021. It's done by adding a dummy field to each of the rows files (ie, ID=1 row all rows), and then doing a 'full out spatial join' to knit them together. Tableau's data model doesn't support adding multiple unrelated files, so things require some sort of database join, even if it is meaningless.
More details here: https://interworks.com/blog/2021/06/18/adding-multiple-spatial-files-as-map-layers-in-tableau/